# Is there any research into the effect of stand up desks on hyperactive symptoms?

Tags: adhd, exercise

The hyperactivity symptom of ADHD includes a compulsion to move or fidget.

In a workplace environment, this can become a distraction to the person with ADHD, as well as the people around him.

It can affect the person's productivity, if they're constantly moving away from their desk to talk to people, make cups of tea, or take breaks for example.

I'm wondering if there's research into techniques for managing the hyperactive symptoms in workplaces, including the usage of stand up desks.

Comment: I've got ADHD and sit at a desk programming all day. I have to get up probably more than 10 times a day to either make tea, go to the toilet, walk into my bosses office etc. Annoyingly no one else in my office drinks tea. I've mentioned standing desks to my boss and he seemed keen until he saw the price of the desks. He's not sure if it is a fad or real. My problem is I exercise a lot (partially to make sure I don't have excess energy) so sometimes I actually need to sit for the entire morning because I've run 20 km (13 miles) into work.

Comment: I've read that in some schools they use gymballs for seats for ADHD kids.